# Processing cannot load GStreamer

Tags: java, gstreamer

I'm trying to play a video on Processing 3.5.3 with the GLvideo library, but I am getting an error message that Processing cannot load GStreamer.

```
import gohai.glvideo.*;
GLMovie video;
boolean forward = true;

void setup() {
  size(560, 406, P3D);
  video = new GLMovie(this, "vid.mp4");
  video.loop();
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  if (video.available()) {
    video.read();
  }
  image(video, 0, 0, width, height);
}

void mousePressed() {
  forward = !forward;
  if (forward == true) {
    video.speed(1.0);
  } else {
    video.speed(-1.0);
  }
}
```

the error message reads

```
GLVideo requires the P2D or P3D renderer.

(java:8347): GLib-CRITICAL **: 21:49:40.265: g_error_free: assertion 'error != NULL' failed
RuntimeException: Could not load GStreamer
```

I'm new to working with Processing on Raspberry Pi, so it may be a simple fix that I'm missing.

any insight?
thanks!

Comment: Where is the problem with Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @Ingo the same sketch runs fine on my mac, I'm using GLVideo because the rPi doesn't support the original video library

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. Found out that Video and GLVideo from contribution manager not working anymore, instead I downloaded [Video library from Github](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/releases) and now examples from Video library are working, but slow. Also, in the GLVideo examples I replaced the GLVideo for Video.

[Check this thread also](https://discourse.processing.org/t/processing-on-raspberry-pi-4-very-slow/15008/6)